# Bindable ObservableCollection not update Calendar UI

Tags: xamarin.forms, binding, calendar, observablecollection

I use [this](https://github.com/rebeccaXam/XamForms.Controls.Calendar) calendar in my project. In Calendar view I added two buttons to select weekends dates. When click in button,"Findes" method added dates in a bindable ObservableCollection SelectedDates. If I add new dates in the list using this method, only update when change month.How is the user interface updated when notifying OnPropertyChanged?

ViewModel

```
    public class CalendarioViewViewModel : MvxViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public CalendarioViewViewModel()
    {
        _dates = new ObservableCollection<DateTime>();
        _dates.Add(new DateTime().AddDays(5));

    }

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get =>  DateTime.Now;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<DateTime> _dates;

    public ObservableCollection<DateTime> Dates
    {
        get { return _dates; }
        set { 
            SetProperty(ref _dates, value);
        }
    }

    private Command _finSemanaCommand;
    public Command FinSemanaCommand =>
        _finSemanaCommand ?? (_finSemanaCommand = new Command(Finde));

    public void Finde()
    {
        Dates.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(7));
        OnPropertyChanged("Dates");


    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {

        var propertyChangedCallback = PropertyChanged;
        propertyChangedCallback?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Xalm view

```
 <calendar:Calendar 
                x:Name="calendar"
                MultiSelectDates="True"
                SelectedBackgroundColor="Khaki"
                SelectedBorderWidth="0"
                BorderColor="Transparent"
                StartDay="Monday"
                EnableTitleMonthYearView="True"
                SelectRange="False"
                SelectedDates="{Binding Dates, Mode=TwoWay}"
                MinDate="{Binding Date}"
                TitleLabelFormat="MMM yyyy"
                HorizontalOptions="Center">
```

Comment: file as issue with the package author.  I don't see anything in the code that makes me think dynamically updating SelectedDates is supported

Answer (score 0):

I found a "solution" to my problem:

CalendarioView.Xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="finde_btn" Text="Finde" BackgroundColor="White" BorderWidth="3" BorderColor="#2DABE2" CornerRadius="10" Grid.Row="2" Clicked="Button_Clicked_Finde"
                    FontSize="13" />

<calendar:Calendar 
                x:Name="calendar"
                MultiSelectDates="True"
                SelectedBorderWidth="0"
                BorderColor="Transparent"
                StartDay="Monday"
                EnableTitleMonthYearView="True"
                SelectRange="False"
                SelectedDates="{Binding Dates, Mode=TwoWay}"
                MinDate="{Binding Date}"
                TitleLabelFormat="MMM yyyy"
                HorizontalOptions="Center">
```

CalendarioView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class CalendarioView : MvxContentPage<CalendarioViewModel>
{
    public CalendarioView ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }


    public void Button_Clicked_Finde(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.Finde(calendar.StartDate);
        calendar.RaiseSpecialDatesChanged();
    }
........
```

CalendandarioViewModel.cs

```
  public class CalendarioViewModel : MvxViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public CalendarioViewModel()
    {
        _dates = new ObservableCollection<DateTime>();

    }

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get =>  DateTime.Now;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<DateTime> _dates;

    public ObservableCollection<DateTime> Dates
    {
        get { return _dates; }
        set { 
            SetProperty(ref _dates, value);
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {

        var propertyChangedCallback = PropertyChanged;
        propertyChangedCallback?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

     public void Finde(DateTime startDate)
    {
        List<DateTime> fechas = GetWeekend(startDate);

        foreach (DateTime dateTime in fechas)
        {
            Dates.Add(dateTime);

        }


        OnPropertyChanged("Dates");


    }
........
```

In resume:

Button click->Call Button_Clicked_Finde in Calendario.xalm.cs->Call Finde function in ViewModel-> When finish execute             calendar.RaiseSpecialDatesChanged() and update UI calendar

Regards